# Is there a lookup table that links Mishnayos with Gemara page

Tags: talmud-gemara, mishna

For example, משנה עירובין פרק ט משנה ד is in תלמוד בבלי on דף צה עמוד א.

Is there a comprehensive table that links all the (relevant) משניות to where they are in תלמוד בבלי?

Comment: Do you only want their "primary" locations or every place they are referenced?

Comment: @DoubleAA only "primary," so one hit per mishna, or else the list would be much longer.

Comment: sefaria is pretty good. It links its mishnayos to its gemara.

Comment: Not exactly what you’re looking for, but if you look at the Rambam’s commentary in the Mishnah printed in the back of the tractate, you’ll see that he quotes the Mishnah and then had the page of the Talmud that Mishnah is found. It is not exactly the standard order of the mishnayot because sometime the Talmud will combine mishnayot or split them